# django сайт на oracle cloud с gunicorn и nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, облако

у меня есть виртуальная машина на oracle cloud, я пытаюсь разместить на ней свой django проект. сделал всё по [этому гайду](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru), но при переходе по айпи машины ничего не открывается.

но если в nginx поменять server name на localhost, то при **curl http://localhost** возвращается страница моего проекта. в настройках django проекта, в **ALOWED_HOST** указаны ай пи машины и локалхост.

моя настройка портов на машине оракл:
[image]

если нужно указать что то ещё, прошу написать об этом в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

всё таки дело было в портах, надо выполнить эти команды:

```
sudo apt install firewalld

sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=80/tcp

sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```